# Microsoft SQL Server multiple locks

Tags: sql, sql-server, locks

I'm currently running Microsoft SQL Express Server.
When one user performs a query without committing it, it locks the entire table.
The problem is that malicious users might "ruin" the database by doing so on purpose.
How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Need more info. What sort of query is it? How are they running the query without committing it?

Comment: They use pyodbc, perform res = con.execute('insert into mytable...'), at that point the table is locked until they res.commit().

Comment: Is this a programmer or a user locking the table? Are you waiting for the user to perform an action before you call commit?

Comment: These are programmers, they can at any point decide to lock that table. Is it possible to set a lock timeout on a table or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand database isolation levels http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems). Most likely you are running queries as seralizable which will have that effect. Try submitting some code.